# SMTP connection error handling, with long connection time

Tags: bash, smtp, timeout

How to handle long connection error/timeout?
This is working , but not in the script ...

```
gtimeout 1 bash -c '3 < /dev/null > /dev/tcp$/{MXHOST}/${MXPORT}
```

This does not handle long waiting/timeout:

```
if (: < /dev/tcp/${MXHOST}/${MXPORT}) 2>/dev/null
# --------------- Creating connection ----------------

if (: < /dev/tcp/${MXHOST}/${MXPORT}) 2>/dev/null
then
    exec 3<> /dev/tcp/${MXHOST}/${MXPORT}
    printf '%-10s %-37s %-37s %-15s\r' "$COUNT" "$TESTEMAIL" "$MXHOST" "Waiting"
    sleep 5
    read -t 5 -u 3 sts line
    connection="$sts $line"
    connsts=${sts:0:3}
    printf '%-10s %-37s %-37s %-15s\r' "$COUNT" "$TESTEMAIL" "$MXHOST" "$connsts"
else
    closests="Failed $?"
    printf '%-10s %-37s %-37s %-15s\n' "$COUNT" "$TESTEMAIL" "$MXHOST" "$closests"
    echo -e "$COUNT \t $TESTEMAIL \t $MXHOST \t $connsts \t $helosts \t $mailsts \t $rcpsts \t $datasts \t $closests" >> resultlog.txt
    continue
fi
```

Comment: please include the version of `bash`. Also include sample values or your variables `$sts, $COUNT, $TESTEMAIL, $maillst, $rcptsts` or replace those values in your sample code with text values. Should another reader expect using `MXHOST=localhost` to be a sufficient test bed? And finally, would you expect this work with any value for `${MXPORT}` (that is not already in use in the system)? Good luck.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was late and i was tired..